# Issue with Poisson regression

Tags: regression, poisson-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

I am analyzing count data (number of negative mental health symptoms). I ran a 1 sample KS test in SPSS and the sig is <0.001 for both a Poisson distribution and a normal distrubtion - indicating that the data does not follow either. There are no zero values whatsoever (values range from 1-9). What other options do I have for a regression analysis?

Comment: How did you perform the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test for the Poisson? The  Kolmogorov-Smirnov is a test for a completely specified distribution. In the normal case I presume you actually did a Lilliefors test. There's a couple of potential traps for the unwary in trying to use a  Kolmogorov-Smirnov for the Poisson.

Comment: Can you explain how the data is collected? Why aren't there any patients with Y = 0 for example where Y is the number of negative mental health symptoms?

Answer (score 3):

There's a number of problems indicated by your post that should be discussed before getting to other options; specifically your approach to choosing between the normal and Poisson (or to ruling both out) have some serious problems.

1. Clearly a count can't be normal; one is discrete and the other continuous, so a test of a discrete variable being normal makes no sense $-$ you already know $H_0$ is false for an absolute certainty, so that hypothesis is pointless to test.
2. You're looking at the marginal distribution, when the distributional model in the GLM is about the *conditional* distribution, so the other test (of it being Poisson) is also useless.
3. A goodness of fit test of a distributional assumption is pretty much unhelpful even if you could test the right thing, since simple parametric assumptions are essentially never true in practice and a large enough sample would always lead you to reject a perfectly suitable approximation.

   So, for example, it can't be exactly Poisson either (there's a finite list of possible symptoms, for one thing). But just because they can't be the exact model doesn't mean you should rule them out.

   The question to ask of the data would better be "Is the normal a reasonable approximation to use?" or "Is the Poisson a reasonable approximation to use?" which you don't answer with a goodness of fit test.
4. A bigger issue is likely to be the way that they have different models for the *spread*, and (assuming you chose canonical link functions), also for the conditional mean. These two are typically much more important than the choice of which of the two conditional distributions you use.
5. Potential endpoint issues: if the lower limit of 1 is because you only include people who would have at least one symptom in your sample (rather than just by happenstance, where a $0$ might have occurred but happened not to), then you'd be dealing with a truncated distribution.

   If the value 9 was a hard upper bound (you only considered 9 symptoms) you should probably consider a model that reflects that bound. A binomial is probably unsuitable (since the distinct symptoms are not equally probable), but a quasi-binomial might not be a bad choice.

There's additional issues still (like the problem of using the same data to choose a model and to perform the inference *conditionally on that selected model*) but I won't get into those details right now.

Comment: Thank you so much I appreciate some of what you are saying though some items are still confusing. To answer a few questions - the data is derived from a select all that apply question - so zero was a possibility, it just so happens that no one selected zero. It is upper bound in that I only included nine potential options (the last being "other"). I ran a one sample KS in SPSS and it gave the option of Poisson with a mean of 1. I also ran the model with GENLIN in SPSS and looked at Goodness of fit - with a value/df of 1.098 - based on this can I assume the data is equidispersed?

Comment: In addition to @Glen_b's list of key points -- you're talking about regression, so which predictors do you have in mind? I don't think you're grasping the nettle of this answer that these tests are some mix of invalid and pointless if regression is your goal and indeed more generally.

Comment: Ok - I think I'm starting to understand. I appreciate the feedback. I only have a single predictor - a dichotomous variable coded 0/1

Comment: " I only have a single predictor - a dichotomous variable coded 0/1" ... What will you be using the model to do? Is the aim simply to compare group means?

Comment: "I ran a one sample KS in SPSS and it gave the option of Poisson with a mean of 1" ... why a mean of 1?